# Download files from the azure data lake

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-data-lake

I upload my files in azure data lake. I try to download that file through asp.net mvc application.I have adl path for that file. I can download below 150 MB files. But i can't download the more then 150 MB files. Time out error came.

My Code in the bellow...

```
public ActionResult Download(string adlpath)
{
    String header = adlpath;
    Console.WriteLine(header);
    string[] splitedStr = header.Split('/');
    var path = GenerateDownloadPaths(adlpath);
    string filename = path["fileName"];
    HttpResponseMessage val = DataDownloadFile(path["fileSrcPath"]);
    byte[] filedata = val.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
    string contentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(filename);
    var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
    {
        FileName = filename,
        Inline = true,
    };
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());

    return File(filedata, contentType);
}

public HttpResponseMessage DataDownloadFile(string srcFilePath)
{
    string DownloadUrl = "https://{0}.azuredatalakestore.net/webhdfs/v1/{1}?op=OPEN&read=true";
    var fullurl = string.Format(DownloadUrl, _datalakeAccountName, srcFilePath);

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", _accesstoken.access_token);
        using (var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent())
        {
            resp = client.GetAsync(fullurl).Result;
        }
    }
    return resp;
}
```

**Image :**
[image]

Comment: Please add the specific error, as text not a screenprint.

Comment: In local i can download the 135 MB file. I host my application in azure there i try download. there download the 1 KB file.

Comment: Not answering your question but you should consider not creating a new `HttpClient` on each request as explained in the [Create and Initialize HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client) section in the ASP.NET Web API documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You should modify your code to use `async` and `await`. Your implementation blocks while retrieving the file and that is probably what times out:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> DataDownloadFile(string srcFilePath)
{
    string DownloadUrl = "https://{0}.azuredatalakestore.net/webhdfs/v1/{1}?op=OPEN&read=true";
    var fullurl = string.Format(DownloadUrl, _datalakeAccountName, srcFilePath);

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", _accesstoken.access_token);
        using (var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent())
        {
            resp = await client.GetAsync(fullurl);
        }
    }
    return resp;
}
```

The return value of the method is changed to `Task<HttpResponseMessage>` and the `async` modifier is added.

Calling `client.GetAsync` is changed to use `await` instead of blocking by retrieving the `Result` property.

Your code may still timeout. I believe that there is a configurable limit on how long a request can take before it is aborted and if you still get a timeout you should investigate this.

Answer (score 0):

Per my understanding, you could try to increase the [HttpClient.Timeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.timeout(v=vs.110).aspx) (100 seconds by default) for your `HttpClient` instance.

> **HttpClient.Timeout**
>
> Gets or sets the timespan to wait before the request times out.
>
> The default value is 100,000 milliseconds (100 seconds).

Moreover, if you host your application via Azure Web App, you may encounter an idle timeout setting of 4 minutes from Azure Load Balancer. You could change the idle timeout setting in Azure VM and Azure Cloud Service. Details you could follow [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-tcp-idle-timeout).